# Using layout_weight for vertical orientated inner LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-linearlayout, android-checkbox

I would like to have maximum 5 CheckBoxes taking equal amount of available space among each other. The amount of CheckBoxes depends on how many answers a question have. So I'm generating the CheckBoxes dynamically but the maximum is 5.

[image]

My main `LinearLayout` has a `horizontal orientation` and the 2 inner `LinearLayout` have a `vertical orientation`. I tried using `android:weightSum=5` for the both of the inner Layouts and `android:layout_weight="1"` for each `CheckBox`. But it doesn't work.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice_solutions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_solution5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice_answers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_answer5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `android:weightSum="5"` from your `LinearLayout`
2. Add `android:layout_weight="1"` to all your `CheckBoxe`s
3. Set `android:layout_height="0dp"` to all your `CheckBoxe`s

Then set visibility GONE programmatically for the ones you want to hide. All the remaining space in the parent layout of the `CheckBoxes` will be filled equally.

Comment: Thank you but there is no difference with these changes.

Comment: You will also need to set `layout_height` of the LinearLayout to something larger than the total of all of the CheckBoxes height. 
`wrap_content` (which you seem to have it set to now for the second set of CheckBoxes) will make the height exactly small enough to fit all the CheckBoxes without any spacing, which is not what you want.

Comment: Do you mean the layout_height of my second inner LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below XML layout i made  some change. it may help you

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_question"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice_solutions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_solution1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_solution2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_solution3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_solution4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_solution5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_multiplechoice_answers"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_answer1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_answer2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_answer3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_answer4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_answer5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```